# Upgrading via brew temurin unable to update

Tags: macos, homebrew, upgrade, package-management

I'm trying to update temurin, I don't even know why it's installed, but I think it's needed for some support program for java.

Can you help me update it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
brew upgrade
==> Casks with 'auto_updates true' or 'version :latest' 
will not be upgraded; pass `--greedy` to upgrade them.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
temurin 21,35 -> 21.0.1,12
==> Upgrading temurin
==> Downloading 
https://github.com/adoptium/temurin21-binaries/releases/download
/jdk-21.0.1%2B12/OpenJDK21U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_21.0.1_12.pkg

==> Uninstalling packages with sudo; the password may be necessary:
==> Purging files for version 21.0.1,12 of Cask temurin
Error: temurin: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_rename - 
(/usr/local/Caskroom/temurin/21,35, /usr/local/Caskroom/temurin/21,35.upgrading)
```

Comment: Run `brew doctor` and fix any issues.

Comment: Please don't post text as an image; see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: @nohillside: I can't find any reference to temurin. https://pastebin.com/ax70CEt9

Comment: Did you follow the advice at the end and then tried again?

Comment: @nohillside: I tried but it didn't work, I couldn't solve the problem with node as you can see from the error message.
Node is installed using nvm, I don't know if this is the problem, I did as it told me by forcing it but it doesn't solve the problem.

All this does not solve the problem with temurin.
https://pastebin.com/p4wWd6vA